# When working with javascript and html a span tag doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a program that calculates some stuff and then prints its results in the middle of a line, thats why I wanted to use a span. So I tried several things I can print my result in a text input but not in a span. As you can see in this code.

```html
<script>
function calculate() {
    //these first two variables are the ones we use to calculate and the third is for saving 
      the calculation
    var 1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("1a").value);
    var 2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("2a").value);
    var 3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("3a").value = 1 * 2);
}
</script>
 <!-- in this tag I aks the user to give two variables -->
 <p style="line-height:1.4">
    give number 1 & 2:
    <input type="text" name="1b" id="1a"/>
    x
    <input type="text" name="2b" id="2a"/>
    <br/>
</p>
<p style="line-height:1.4">
    <input type="button" value="calculate" onClick="calculate();"/>
    <br/>
</p>
<!--in this tag I print the result but in the span it doesn't work while the text input does print 
  the result -->
<p> 
    <input type="text" name="3b" id="3a"/>
    The result is <span id="3a"></span>. 
</p>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you'd like the output to look like? Saying "I want to use tag X" when it's not clear what you intend "tag x" to accomplish is not useful.

Comment: Note: the `<input>` and `<br>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

An element's id should be unique across all other elements to work effectively. In the code posted, you have the id '3' associated with 2 different elements. This will cause unexpected behavior since when the element with id '3' is asked for, the browser's DOM API is probably just returning the first matching element. To make it work, give the input and the span 2 different id's that are unique to all the other elements as well

Comment: Do you mean I have to make the names of the variables and the id's different? Because if I do so the result is still the same it doesn't print anything in my the span tag.

Comment: No, the state that it is in now should throw errors because the variable names cannot be numbers. I was saying that the ids of different html elements must be different from one another. But as others have said you should set the 'innerText' of the span, since 'value' is not a property of a span.

Comment: it still didn't work, the code I uploaded here is obiously a simplified version but still I tried everything that people told me here and it didn't help at all. It's a program were I try to do several calculation in one function but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

In order to print the result in the span tag, you gotta use innerText instead of value:

```
document.getElementById('3a').innerText = (1*2);
```

Also, it's better to change the name of the variables in order to be more clear an not have issues to understand the code. You could use value1 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use `innerHTML` for non-form elements:

```js
function calculate() {
    const one = parseFloat(document.getElementById("1a").value);
    const two = parseFloat(document.getElementById("2a").value);
    document.getElementById("3a").innerHTML = one * two;
}
```

```html
 <p style="line-height:1.4">
    give number 1 & 2:
    <input type="text" name="1b" id="1a"/>
    x
    <input type="text" name="2b" id="2a"/>
    <br/>
</p>
<p style="line-height:1.4">
    <input type="button" value="calculate" onClick="calculate();"/>
    <br/>
</p>
<p> 
    The result is <span id="3a"></span>. 
</p>
```